# Android и распознавание различных устройств

Tags: android, java

Есть Android-клиент и web-сервер. Требуется распознавать различные устройства одного пользователя. Знаю, что у всех телефонов есть IMEI, но что делать с планшетами и устройствами, не имеющими gsm-модуль? Есть ли какой-нибудь идентификатор? И как его считать с устройства программно?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Самому генерить еще больше "не вариант", т. к. достаточно просто переустановить приложение, и - вуаля - у тебя новый айди! В общем, как говорится, "тема сисек не раскрыта..." То есть единого решения нет. Все извращаются, как могут...

**Обновление**

И даже UUID тут не при чем. С Bluetooth используется только MAC-адрес BT. Кстати, можете попытаться использовать как раз его для идентификации... Думаю, что устройств без блютуса намного меньше, чем устройств без GSM...

Не уверен, что это возможно, но еще можно попробовать достать MAC адрес WIFI. Если получится, то вы покроете 99.99% всех устройств.

Comment: Я далёк от темы, просветите - эта штука IMEI используется при Bluetooth соединении?

P.S. А нет, с UUID перепутал.

Answer (score 1):

Универсального уникального номера нет.

Есть [Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). Генерируется случайно при первом запуске OS. Может быть изменен после factory reset. Также встречаются устройства с одинаковым постоянным его значением (в основном, дешевые китайские телефоны).

Есть IMEI, MAC адреса bluetooth и Wi-Fi адаптеров.

У некоторых устройств есть серийный номер [Build#SERIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL).

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, что лучшим решением наверное будет комбинация нескольких идентификаторов:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

telephonyManager=( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );

deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); //IMEI для GSM или MEID/ESN для CDMA

subscriberId = telephonyManager.getSubscriberId(); //IMSI для GSM

androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class );
serialnum = (String)(   get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno", "unknown" )); //серийный номер

myId=deviceId+subscriberId+androidId+serialNum;  //конечный Id
```

При этом надо понимать, что `deviceId` и `subscriberId` будут только при наличии GSM/CDMA модуля, а `androidId`, как правильно писали ранее, при factory reset скидывается, а `serialNum` местами будет пуст